# MVC design pattern in Swing thin client

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm developing an application which have many swing thin client UIs accessing a common server. 
Clients uses RMI to communicate with servers.

**How can I implement MVC pattern in this type of applications?**

EDIT:

I'm thinking to have `Controller` in both client and server side. The `ClientController` listens to all the events in `View` i.e Client UI and passes the information to  `Controller` in server side. The `ServerController` then access `Model` with `Service` for the `Model`. I thought of `Controller` in both client and server side so that any small events that occured in Client side can be handled in Client side without needing to call Controller in Server with overhead of RMI.

**Is this the proper way to implement MVC?**

Comment: The thin client is your view.  The data classes are your model.  The server contains the controller classes, which do persistence and application logic.

Comment: I'm thinking to have `Controller` in both client and server side. The client Controller listens to all the events in `View` i.e Client UI and passes the information to  `Controller` in server side. The server Controller then access `Model` with `Service` for the `Model`. Is this the proper way to implement MVC?

Comment: It is an acceptable way to do it.  There are trade-offs both to making the client code thinner and to making it less thin.  The best solution depends on the capabilities of the server, the typical speed of a client's network connection, and your means of distributing and updating the client software (such as Java Web Start).

Answer (score 0):

mvc originally referred to mini architecture on one machine (http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html). since yours is a web app, take a look at the see also's at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller. also see derivations and extansions at: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelViewController. one of these may be what you want.